# regex - Match a known character between two unknown words but not between unknown numbers

Tags: regex

I am using 'atom' tool to replace a known character (comma) between two words but not between numbers. Here's the sample

**Input**

0613256,4565436,abc,def

49821339,35355,ghij,kl

750024,0376403,mn,opqrst

**Output**

0613256,4565436,abcdef

49821339,35355,ghijkl

750024,0376403,mnopqrst

Comment: A regex does not replace stuff. It only matches.

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: @klutt I meant to match.

Comment: Is your input a csv? Is there always the same number of fields? What language do you use?

Comment: @casimiretHippolyte yes, it's a csv and there's always the same number of fields.

Comment: I am using 'atom' tool to replace the comma only between the words but not between numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `sublime text` instead, as `atom` uses JavaScript *regex* engine hence, its pretty hard to accomplish what you exactly want. In *sublime text*, you can use the following *regex* to find commas only between words ...

```
(?<=[a-z]),
```

- `(?<=[a-z])` looks behind for a word character
- `,` matches a literal comma

[image]

now that the comma is matched, you can replace it by an empty character.

Answer (score 0):

A sed command to do the substitution you originally asked for is this:

```
sed -e 's/\([a-z]\),\([a-z]\)/\1\2/g'
```

A regex to just match the pattern is this:

```
[a-z],[a-z]
```